error: ‘AT_FDCWD’ was not declared in this scope
      |                  ^~~~
/home/naga/Naga/E-Linux/apt/apt-main/apt-pkg/contrib/fileutl.cc: In function ‘std::string GetTempDirEnv(const char*)’:
/home/naga/Naga/E-Linux/apt/apt-main/apt-pkg/contrib/fileutl.cc:3101:20: error: ‘AT_FDCWD’ was not declared in this scope
 3101 |          faccessat(AT_FDCWD, tmpdir, R_OK | W_OK | X_OK, AT_EACCESS) != 0) // current user has rwx access to directory
      |                    ^~~~~~~~
/home/naga/Naga/E-Linux/apt/apt-main/apt-pkg/contrib/fileutl.cc:3101:58: error: ‘AT_EACCESS’ was not declared in this scope; did you mean ‘DN_ACCESS’?
 3101 |          faccessat(AT_FDCWD, tmpdir, R_OK | W_OK | X_OK, AT_EACCESS) != 0) // current user has rwx access to directory
      |                                                          ^~~~~~~~~~
      |                                                          DN_ACCESS
make[2]: *** [apt-pkg/CMakeFiles/apt-pkg.dir/build.make:328: apt-pkg/CMakeFiles/apt-pkg.dir/contrib/fileutl.cc.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:486: apt-pkg/CMakeFiles/apt-pkg.dir/all] Error 2

the headerfile fcntl.h and unistd.h are present user/local/include. In that file ‘AT_FDCWD’ are not defined. Then i replaced the exist header file with same header file which has ‘AT_FDCWD’ are defined. So after this error resovled. but i geeting continious error function decerations. if i am resolving by replacing header file.

What header file i need to include to over come this error for building apt package?

